Calculated column to add hours to Date Only field
I have a sharepoint online date field named DueDate of type Date/Time that allow to enter Date Only (without time).
And i choice field named DueDatetime with these values:-
12:00 AM
12:30 AM
1:00 AM
1:30 AM
2:00 AM
2:30 AM
3:00 AM
3:30 AM
4:00 AM
4:30 AM
5:00 AM
5:30 AM
6:00 AM
6:30 AM
7:00 AM
7:30 AM
8:00 AM
8:30 AM
9:00 AM
9:30 AM
10:00 AM
10:30 AM
11:00 AM
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
1:00 PM
1:30 PM
2:00 PM
2:30 PM
3:00 PM
3:30 PM
4:00 PM
4:30 PM
5:00 PM
5:30 PM
6:00 PM
6:30 PM
7:00 PM
7:30 PM
8:00 PM
8:30 PM
9:00 PM
9:30 PM
10:00 PM
10:30 PM
11:00 PM
11:30 PM
now i want to create a calculated column which will add the number of hours based on the choice selection to the due date, is this possible? i do not want to modify the DueDate field to allow Date and time, since i am using Search web parts and i need to control the time value, seems by default the time in search will be shown in UTC and not based on the site collection time zone... so can i created such as calculated column?

Using VALUE(text), maybe we can accomplish this. See the formula and screenshot below.
=DueDate+VALUE(DueDatetime)


[DueDate] => Date type column
[DueDatetime] => Choice type column with choices described in the requirements
Please note, days can directly be added to a Date type column. Here VALUE() is returning a numeric value representing day from the mid-night.

